# App not launching with AppDelegate, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions() never gets called

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, appdelegate

I'm new to iOS programming. I am trying to make an iOS version of an Android app I have.

Before everything worked but then I added a TabBarController as the main UIViewController and the app started launching in that activity.

This is my storyboard:
[This is my storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ct7NP.png)

The AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions():

```
let tokenLogin: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "tokenLogin")
if !tokenLogin {
    self.showLoginScreen()
}
```

So the idea is that if the user never logged in, the log in screen will appear and if the log in is valid, the tab bar activity will launch.

Right now, because AppDelegate is never executed I can't make the user log in.

Any help would be apreciated.

EDIT:

I changed the 'Main Interface' to blank as DivyaS suggested. But still `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions()` isn't executing (I checked that is the latest version of the function). I put a print at the very begining to check but nothing. The screen is just black.
[image]

Comment: As a side point, you should never be storing your login token (or any other sensitive information) in `UserDefaults` as it is not secure at all. Ideally you should be using the keychain for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to general tab in target and scroll down to "Deployment Info" then reset main interface with blank.

Then Inside AppDelegate.swift you need put your logic to choose View Controller.
Example:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    if UserDefaults.sharedInstance.getIsUserLogin(){

        // user has configured his profile and he is ready to use the app
        // configure tab bar
        let vc = TabBarViewController()
        navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: vc)

    } else {

        // user is not login 
        let vc = LoginViewController()
        navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: vc)
    }
    window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
```

Comment: I feel like you are right, I've seen a lot of people leaving that field blank, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Then check inside your info.plist for "Main storyboard file base name" name. if present then delete. and have you clean your build?